# Backbone JS automatically routing back to default

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I've just started foundational work for a Backbone JS SPA (single page application). I'm using the basic Underscore templating support, and am having issues with unexpected routing occurring.

Basically, the sign up view is shown initially as expected, POSTs succesfully when I click a button and I have it navigate to a simple test view. However, the test view is quickly rendered and then I get re-routed to the default sign up view again.

I see the history of the test page and if I hit the back button I go back to that test view which works fine. I see there is some event being triggered in Backbone which is routing me back to the blank fragment (sign up page), but I have no idea why. I've tried messing with the replace and trigger options on the navigate call with no luck.

As a side note, the start() and stop() View functions were adapted from this article: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/ . I tried removing this and it had no effect.

```
$(document).ready( function(){

     Backbone.View.prototype.start = function() {
         console.debug('starting');
         if (this.model && this.modelEvents) {
            _.each(this.modelEvents,
                function(functionName, event) {
                    this.model.bind(event, this[functionName], this);
                }, this);
        }
         console.debug('started');
        return this;
     };

     Backbone.View.prototype.stop = function() {
         console.debug('stopping');

        if (this.model && this.modelEvents) {
            _.each(this.modelEvents,
                function(functionName, event) {
                    this.model.unbind(event, this[functionName]);
            }, this);
        }
        console.debug('stopped');
        return this;
    };

    var myApp = {};

    myApp.SignUp = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot:"rest/v1/user",

        defaults: {
            emailAddress: "email@me.com",
            firstName: "First Name",
            lastName: "Last Name",
            password: "",
            confirmPassword: ""
          }
    });


    myApp.SignUpView = Backbone.View.extend({

         el: $('#bodyTarget'),

         modelEvents: {
             'change' : 'render'
         },

         render: function(){
             document.title = "Sign Up Page";

             // Compile the template using underscore
             var template = _.template( $("#signUpTemplate").html(), this.model.toJSON());
             // Load the compiled HTML into the Backbone "el"
             this.$el.html( template );
             return this;
         },

         events: {
             "click .signUpButton": "signUp"  
         },

         signUp: function() {
             bindFormValues(this);
             this.model.save(this.model.attributes, {error: this.signUpFailure});
             myApp.router.navigate("test",  {trigger: true});
         },

         signUpFailure: function(model, response) {
             alert("Failure: " + response);
         }
    });

    myApp.TestView = Backbone.View.extend({

         el: $('#bodyTarget'),

         modelEvents: {
             'change' : 'render'
         },

         render: function() {
             document.title = "Test Page";
             this.$el.html( "<div>this is a test view</div>");
             return this;
         }
    });

    // for now, just pull values from form back into model
    function bindFormValues(view) {
        var mod = view.model;
        var el = view.$el;
        var updates = {};
        for (var prop in mod.attributes) {
            var found = el.find('* [name="' + prop + '"]');
            if (found.length > 0) {
                updates[prop] = found.val();    
            }
        }
        mod.set(updates/*, {error: errorHandler}*/);
    }

    // routers
    myApp.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            'test': 'test',
            '': 'home',
        },

        home: function() {
            console.debug('home:enter');
            this.signUpView = new myApp.SignUpView({model: new myApp.SignUp()});
            this.showView(this.signUpView);
            console.debug('home:exit');
        },


        test: function() {
            console.debug('test:enter');
            this.testView = new myApp.TestView({model: new myApp.SignUp()});
            this.showView(this.testView);
            console.debug('test:exit');
        },

        showView: function(view) {
            if (this.currentView) {
                this.currentView.stop();
            }
            this.currentView = view.start().render();
          }
     });

     myApp.router = new myApp.Router();
     Backbone.history.start();

});
```

My HTML page just brings in the relevant scripts and has the div element bodyTarget which is injected with the views when it loads.

**Edit:** Duh, I found the problem. It turns out I needed to prevent event propagation on the call to signUp() by returning false.

Comment: As mentioned in my edit, I found the issue. I needed to prevent event propagation on the call to signUp() by returning false.

Comment: You are allowed to answer your own questions, AFAIK you'll have to wait a day before you can accept it though.

Comment: You should answer your own question so people don't have to read the whole thing to see you figured it out